# Angular 4.0 Teradata data-table ng-template for all columns

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, teradata-covalent

does anybody know if there is a way to apply an < ng-template > for all columns in the < td-data-table > by declaring only one < ng-template > and not one for every column. Something like:

```
<ng-template tdDataTableTemplate="{{columns}}" let-value="value">
    <div>
        <span>{{value.content}}</span>
        <br>
        <span *ngIf="enabler">{{value.subcontent}}</span>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```